# Where to find Status details for SSIS execution id in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have created an SSIS Package and deployed it on Server.

While execution of Package i can see the report of Execution.

i want to know that in which table SSIS execution id's information is stored?

like if execution id= 2 that means packge is running when 4 that means failed when 7 that means success.

i want to know all status ID's details. I thing there would be a table in ssis db where information would be saved against the status id. can some body help me>

Comment: No there isn't a table for that in SSISDB but there are numerous references online

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Status is saved in the View [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] and the table underneath is [SSISDB].[internal].[operations] .

The details of Status can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database

> **status**    ***int***
> The status of the operation. The possible values are
> created (1), running (2), canceled (3), failed (4), pending (5), ended
> unexpectedly (6), succeeded (7), stopping (8), and completed (9).

If you need a dimension table for Status I think you have to create one yourself , it should be pretty easy from official documents.

Here is full list of the official docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/views-integration-services-catalog

> This section describes the Transact-SQL views that are available for
> administering Integration Services projects that have been deployed to
> an instance of SQL Server.
>
> Query the Integration Services views to inspect objects, settings, and
> operational data that are stored in the SSISDB catalog.
>
> The default name of the catalog is SSISDB. The objects that are stored
> in the catalog include projects, packages, parameters, environments,
> and operational history.
>
> You can use the database views and stored procedures directly, or
> write custom code that calls the managed API. Management Studio and
> the managed API query the views and call the stored procedures that
> are described in this section to perform many of their tasks.
>
> **In This Section**
>
> [catalog.catalog_properties (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-catalog-properties-ssisdb-database)
>
> Displays the properties of the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.effective_object_permissions (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-effective-object-permissions-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the effective permissions for the current principal for all objects in the
> Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.environment_variables (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-environment-variables-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the environment variable details for all environments in the Integration
> Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.environments (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-environments-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the environment details for all environments in the Integration Services catalog.
> Environments contain variables that can be referenced by Integration
> Services projects.
>
> [catalog.execution_parameter_values (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-execution-parameter-values-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the actual parameter values that are used by Integration Services packages
> during an instance of execution.
>
> [catalog.executions (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the instances of package execution in the Integration Services catalog. Packages that are
> executed with the Execute Package task run in the same instance of
> execution as the parent package.
>
> [catalog.explicit_object_permissions (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-explicit-object-permissions-ssisdb-database)
> Displays only the permissions that have been explicitly assigned to the user.
>
> [catalog.extended_operation_info (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-extended-operation-info-ssisdb-database)
> Displays extended information for all operations in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.folders (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-folders-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the folders in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.object_parameters (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-object-parameters-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the parameters for all packages and projects in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.object_versions (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-object-versions-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the versions of objects in the Integration Services catalog. In this release, only
> versions of projects are supported in this view.
>
> [catalog.operation_messages (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-operation-messages-ssisdb-database)
> Displays messages that are logged during operations in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.operations (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-operations-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the details of all operations in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.packages (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-packages-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the details for all packages that appear in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.environment_references (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-environment-references-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the environment references for all projects in the Integration Services
> [catalog][]
>
> [catalog.projects (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-projects-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the details for all projects that appear in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.validations (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-validations-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the details of all project and package validations in the Integration Services catalog.
>
> [catalog.master_properties (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-master-properties-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the properties of the Integration Services Scale Out Master.
>
> [catalog.worker_agents (SSISDB Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-worker-agents-ssisdb-database)
> Displays the information of Integration Services Scale Out Worker.

Answer (score 1):

Execution id, i.e. operation id is used to identify the operation.
In my opinion this is very confusing, but you can see it from the structure of the catalog.executions view.
from operations view you can get messages, from executions - packages.